# Google Maps API Reload Markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I add Markers in the Google Map API with the following code

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
         .position(point)
         .title(text)
         .snippet(textinfo)
         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
}
```

How can I make them save (I guess in onResume and in OnPause) so they will appear when i re-launch the app and not dissapear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to automatically save the markers between launches of the map, so you either have to save the info to recreated it, or you could make use of the fact that `googleMap.addMarker()` returns a Marker object, and serialize that to [SharedPerferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and then re-add it the next time your app launches.

See the following:
[addMarker()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions))
and
[Marker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker)

For an example of using Shared Preferences see the following [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), but here is the example from the developers guide.

public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
   setSilent(silent);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
}
```

}